# Using Twilio Verification with Parse

Tags: parse-platform, twilio

My application uses Twilio but requires that new phone numbers become verified by the user, which makes sense of course.  I don't have the option to use PHP for my application so I want to use Parse since it already connects super well with Twilio.  Is there some way to ask the user to verify their phone but through using Parse or some way on my webpage?

https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/verified

What I'm looking for is something like

```
var client = require('twilio')('AC461d3f5fa9b34098d83e19417d88608c', '93e934c729223531780d8a0851d14ab3');

// Send an SMS message
client.sendSms({........
```

But instead with

client.verifyCallerID({........

For now I have a method that does this, but it's not working...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("verifyPhoneNumber", function(request, response) {
  var url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC461d3f5fa9b34098d83e19417d88608c/OutgoingCallerIds.json";

  var httpOptions = {
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
          PhoneNumber: request.params.phoneNumber
        },
        username: "AC461d3f5fa9b34098d83e19417d88608c:{MyAuthToken}"
    };
  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest(httpOptions).then(
      function(httpResponse) {
          response.success(httpResponse.text);
      },
      function(httpResponse) {
          console.log(httpResponse);
          var error = new Error();
          error.code = httpResponse.status;
          error.message = httpResponse.text;
          response.error(error);
      }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Node.js has pretty much the same functions as ParseCloud uses to connect with Twilio.

```
client.outgoingCallerIds.create({
       phoneNumber: request.params.phoneNumber
     }, function(err, responseData) {
       if (err) {
         response.success(err);
       } else {
         response.success(responseData.body);
       }
 });
```